# Unable to map the latitude and longitude posistions

Tags: java, android, json, api, google-maps

Edit:

Have added the relevant classes to be able to access each element layer of the JSON array.

Currently when (still) trying to access the location I am calling a new object of the datawrapper class, I can see how the implementation of the code to access the location should work but at the moment I'm receiving the error of:

```
The method getGeometry() is undefined for the type List.
```

I am getting Eclipse to autocomplete the location object by showing 'getLongitude()' and 'getLatitude()' methods but they should be 'getLat()' and 'getLng()' methods.

I see how accessing the objects in order is allowing me to get the long and lat but still the error above has thrown me.

Here are my serpate JSON classes as they stand:

Datawrapper:

```
package com.example.restfulweb;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class DataWrapper<GeoResult> {

    List<GeoName> results;

public List<GeoName> getResults() {
    return results;
}

public void setResults(List<GeoName> results) {
    this.results = results;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public DataWrapper fromJson(String jsonString)
{
    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, DataWrapper.class);
}
```

}

GeoName class:

```
package com.example.restfulweb;

public class GeoName {

private String id;
private Geometry geometry;
private String name;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Geometry getGeometry() {
    return geometry;
}
public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
    this.geometry = geometry;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Geometry Class:

```
package com.example.restfulweb;

public class Geometry {
private Location location;

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

}

Location class:

package com.example.restfulweb;

```
public class Location {
private Double lat;
private Double lng;

public Double getLat() {
    return lat;
}
public void setLat(Double lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}
public Double getLng() {
    return lng;
}
public void setLng(Double lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}
```

}
}

As shown all Getter and setter methods match. As its a list of the returned objects Im not sure why this error is being thrown?

How the code stands to access the layers:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        DataWrapper dataWrapper = new DataWrapper();

        Location location = dataWrapper.getResults().getGeometry().getLocation();
```

Comment: Can you add the code that loads the GeoName objects from JSON?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have added the methods used to return the JSON results object used for mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mappings are off, in that the hierarchy of data mapped in your target class does not match the JSON structure. The `name` and `location` fields are at different levels in the JSON, and neither of those fields is at the root level from which you are mapping. If you want to serialize using 'strong types', you need to define a few more classes. Something closer to this:

```
public class Location {
    private Double lat;
    private Double lng;

    // Constructors, getters, setters
}

public class Geometry {
    private Location location;

    // Constructors, getters, setters
}

public class GeoResult {
    private String id;
    private Geometry geometry;
    private String name;

    // Constructors, getters, setters
}

public class DataWrapper {
    private List<GeoResult> results;

    // Constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Using versions of these classes, deserializing the JSON data into the `DataWrapper` class should now populate down the object hierarchy, in a manner matching the natural hierarchy of the data. You can retrieve location data with code similar to:

```
Location location = dataWrapper.getResults(0).getGeometry().getLocation();
```

Comment: Great answer thank you. Just trying to getmy head around it all. So basically i need to break each level of the JSON response into a class? getting and setting each 'attribute' i.e the lat and long?

Comment: Yes, when deserializing into a type, you need to map each level in the JSON as a class.

Comment: Many thanks again, that makes sense. I can see how the layers of the classes link together to produce the JSON 'layer' but where im now stuck on is the method for retrieving the lat and long themselves. I have put the 'geometry' class within the GeoName class. Do i need to create a new instance of the DataWrapper class to retrieve the lat and long? Or is it a case of getting the lat and long from that location object i.e location.lat and location.lng?

Comment: I included a line of code illustrating how you can get the 'lat' and 'long' fields for any particular result/geometry instance.

Comment: I have edited my code as it currently stands. The object path to the location class is currently throwing an error that List is undefined.Eclipse is detecting a getLongitude() and getLatitude() methods but these should be getLat() and getLng(). Sorry for all the questions but JSON and accessing classes this way is a little new to me.

Comment: You have to import `java.util.List` in whatever class is showing that error. Also, you must have named your fields 'latitude' and 'longitude' in your `Location` class, you might want to double check that.

Comment: I did think of the List import aswell, put upon adding it into the 'GeoName' class where 'getGeometry()' is implemneted, Eclipse gives the warning that it is never used. As for the location class, I accidently added the Geometry class twice in the edit, I have reupdated the code with the location class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25161/discussion-between-perception-and-user1352057)

Comment: `private Double lat/long` If you use class type of Double here, you will get the localization WRONG. For example, if you post these data to server, you will see Arabic numbers for people running your app in Arabic language Android. I made the same mistake and it took me days to figured out why the lat/long post the server as Arabic for some people. Use always primitive types for lat/long.